# Apache web server: mask URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

Is there a way to mask a URL using Apache. I am not an Apache admin, but an IIS admin but recently I've been involved in a project that includes connfiguring Apache (so, please answer like you would to a newbie).
We have a URL structure like this:

```
HTTP://subdomain.company.com/company/country
```

We want to simplify this by goingo for:

```
http://subdomain.company.com/country
```

Can this be accomplished by using rewrite rules? I mean, can we keep the /company/country folder structure but mask the URL to look like we're only using /country, is this a matter of rewrite rules?
Or are the other routing options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.company.com
RewriteRule ^((?!company/).*)$ /company/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! will this do a full redirection or will it keep the URL in the browser as http://subdomain.company.com/country ? Just to know if there's a way to just mask as opposed to redirect.

Comment: This will not do full redirection and will keep URL as `subdomain.company.com/country` in the browser.